# mysql query to display messages with sender and reciever

Tags: mysql

my messaging schema is like this

```
USER  
id  
name
```

```
MESSAGE  
id  
messagetitle    
sender_id    
receiver_id
```

I want to display `messagetitle` with sender and receivers name

for example MySQL query should display :

```
+--------------+------------+--------------+
| MessageTitle | SenderName | Recievername |
+--------------+------------+--------------+
| Important    | Raj        | Vijay        |
| Solution     | Vijay      | Raj          |
+--------------+------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following sql for your solution:

```
SELECT 
    m.messagetitle AS MessageTitle
    ,u1.Name AS SenderName
    ,u2.Name AS Recievername 
FROM MESSAGE m 
INNER JOIN USER u1 ON u1.id = m.sender_id 
INNER JOIN USER u2 ON u2.id = m.receiver_id
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/c8a44/1)**

Comment: tnks budd really appreciate quick help @JLC007

Answer (score 1):

Should be a plain old simple join, freehand something like;

```
SELECT m.messagetitle, s.name sender, r.name receiver
FROM message m
JOIN user s ON m.sender_id=s.id
JOIN user r ON m.receiver_id=r.id
```

Comment: tnku so much for quick reply @Joachim Isaksson